# Compile GCC with MinGW for ARM

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling

I'm trying to compile GCC on Windows with MinGW for ARM. I'm really a linux-/make-noob, so please don't hit me if my question is dumb. I just downloaded and installed MinGW. I then mingw-get install ed mpfr, gmp and mpc. I then downloaded the GCC source code (4.7.2) and copied it to a directory on my PC. I opened the MinGW shell, browsed to the directory and entered:

```
./configure --target=arm-none-eabi --with-arch=armv6 --disable-shared
make
```

Everything went good, I thought, until I got the error:

```
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile 
see 'config.log' for more details.
```

Well, I already googled the error and found http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#configure_suffix But this doesn't really help me. The config.log file also doesn't really tell me anything useful. Any idea what I should try?

Just in case anyone wants to see this: The config.log file: http://pastebin.com/FY5DZXfw

Comment: Have you built cross compiler or trying to cross compile with usual MinGW distribution?

Comment: @Sergey I don't really get the question, I definitely can't generate ARM binaries with the usual MinGW distribution, as far as I know.

Comment: @cooky451 : Are you trying to cross-compile a linux kernel or will you compile userland-software, with your gcc? Did you try [this](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HostedCrossCompilerHOWTO)? Is seems this [site](http://web.archive.org/web/20140102224941/http://gnuarm.com/) has binaries for windows (no need to compile gcc)...